# CHOCO Constraint Solver features

Tags: constraints, constraint-programming, choco

Does anyone know whether CHOCO supports the following:

```
Dynamic Variable Ordering
```

and

```
Precedence Constraints ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Precedence Constraint, I hope you can find something that suits your needs with :
Choco.precedence(TaskVariable, TaskVariable)
Choco.precedence(TaskVariable, TaskVariable, int)

Both methods return a constraint that you can add to model. Unfortunately it seems that this constraint is not documented yet so I can't be more specific.

There also seem to be other constraints related to precedence : Choco.precedenceReified, Choco.precedenceimplied, Choco.precedencedisjoint.

For more information I would suggest to download the latest API :
http://www.emn.fr/z-info/choco-solver/choco-documentation.html

Hope it can help,
Bye